# How to get the contents of application/json type in php?

Tags: php, header

I used `file_get_contents('php://input')` but sometimes it won't work. I checked the headers using `getallheaders()` and the `Content-Length` has always the size of the content but sometimes `file_get_contents('php://input')` returns null.

Comment: Why its php:// and not file://.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
$handle = fopen('php://input','r');
$jsonInput = fgets($handle);
$decoded = json_decode($jsonInput,true);

  //$decoded['tag'] you data
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I always thought it was the cache because it works again if I cleared it. Anyway, Thanks!